# Displaying one result on a query with LIMIT 10

Tags: php, mysql, rss

Today i'm makeing this new question because this is not posible to display one result on a query with limit 10.

Here is the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articol WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $titlu = $row["titlu"];
    $data = $row["data"];
    $desc = $row["continut"];
    $part = strip_tags($desc); 
 }
```

And this is the echo to display

```
<link>http://dirlink.ro/articol.php?art_id=<?php echo $id; ?></link>
<title><?php echo $titlu; ?></title>
<description><?php echo substr($part,0,180); ?> ...{Citeste tot} </description>
<pubDate><?php echo $data; ?></pubDate>
```

The same code is putted on other page, for other category of my website and it's work just fine. I don't understand why at this section is echoing only one result.

Comment: can you reformat this to be human readable?  Very difficult to see what's going on here.

Comment: Are you sure there are 10 results to be found? It would only show one if only one existed.

Comment: @Jeremy: I was about to say the same thing

Comment: yes i'm sure , i have 96 added articles with status = 1

Answer (score 4):

All you are doing is reassigning the variables, you are not outputting them, so you will only ever end up outputting the last result.

What you need to do is call them inside the `while` loop:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articol WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $id = $row["id"];
  $titlu = $row["titlu"];
  $data = $row["data"];
  $desc = $row["continut"];
  $part = strip_tags($desc);
  print "<link>http://dirlink.ro/articol.php?art_id=$id</link>\n"
  ."<title>$titlu</title>\n"
  ."<description>".substr($part,0,180)." ...{Citeste tot} </description>\n"
  ."<pubDate>$data</pubDate>\n";
}
```

Edited a little after I read the question properly... [blush]

Comment: with print , result me the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use mysql_fetch_assoc($result) for named elements, but I could be mistaken.

your echos need to be in the loop if you are trying to list them all; otherwise your values are going to be overwritten and only the last row will be displayed.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` should be used here, although `mysql_fetch_array()` will work just as well. The difference is that `mysql_fetch_array()` gets a mixed indexed/associative array, whereas `mysql_fetch_assoc()` gets just the associative keys (which is more memory efficient, unless you actually need the indexed keys as well).

Comment: same if i use : mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: the error seams to be from some html codes who are added in the row like `<htmlcode><htmlcode>` i don't know why but i added some new articles without any html code used like that and it's working, but stil doesn't work if i is added like `<htmlcode><htmlcode>`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it: I checked the RSS field with rssvalidator.org and there it showed me the errors and how to fix it.

So I fixed the error, which seem to originate from some `&circi;`, which is a character of a Romanian language.